# How to use IF condition to swap two columns value in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to swap values of From and To columns if Direction equals to 2 if Direction is Inner Joined from another table

```
From    To       Direction
4489    4496     1
73      76       1
76      79       1
73      76       1
1333    1336     1
10      12       1
1290    1294     2

 SELECT               CONCAT('\\',exc.ExcavationId,'\\', fa.FileAttachmentId, '.pdf')AS ExcavationFileID,FLOOR(gs.ChainageFrom) as From,
                                  FLOOR(gs.ChainageTo) as To,gs.BlastName, fa.Name as PDFName, exc.CreatedDate as ExcDate,
                                  fa.CreatedDate as file_att_date,ma.LOMDriveName, fa.Description as file_des, ma.Direction

       FROM Excavation as exc
                            INNER JOIN ExcavationGSLocation as exc_gs ON exc_gs.ExcavationId=exc.ExcavationId
                            INNER JOIN GSLocation as gs on gs.GSLocationId=exc_gs.GSLocationId
                            INNER JOIN ExcavationAttachment as exc_attach ON exc_attach.ExcavationId=exc.ExcavationId
                            INNER JOIN FileAttachment as fa ON fa.FileAttachmentId=exc_attach.FileAttachmentId
                            INNER JOIN MultiAttributes as ma on ma.MultiAttributeId = gs.MultiAttributeId
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I would assume OP is looking for a `SELECT` statement rather than an `UPDATE`, though without more details it's not apparent. `SELECT IF(Direction = 1, \`From\`, \`To\`) as \`From\`, IF(Direction = 1, \`To\`, \`From\`) as \`To\` FROM table;`

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to swap it in a Select you can try with:

```
SELECT CONCAT('\\',exc.ExcavationId,'\\', fa.FileAttachmentId, '.pdf') AS ExcavationFileID,
      (Case When ma.Direction = 2 Then FLOOR(gs.ChainageTo) Else FLOOR(gs.ChainageFrom) End) as From,
      (Case When ma.Direction = 2 Then FLOOR(gs.ChainageFrom) Else FLOOR(gs.ChainageTo) End) as To,
      
      gs.BlastName, 
      fa.Name as PDFName, 
      exc.CreatedDate as ExcDate,
      fa.CreatedDate as file_att_date,
      ma.LOMDriveName, 
      fa.Description as file_des, 
      ma.Direction

FROM Excavation as exc
INNER JOIN ExcavationGSLocation as exc_gs ON exc_gs.ExcavationId=exc.ExcavationId
INNER JOIN GSLocation as gs on gs.GSLocationId=exc_gs.GSLocationId
INNER JOIN ExcavationAttachment as exc_attach ON exc_attach.ExcavationId=exc.ExcavationId
INNER JOIN FileAttachment as fa ON fa.FileAttachmentId=exc_attach.FileAttachmentId
INNER JOIN MultiAttributes as ma on ma.MultiAttributeId = gs.MultiAttributeId
```

If you want to update the values in the table, then can try with this:

```
Update gs
Set gs.ChainageTo = ChainageFrom,
    gs.ChainageFrom = ChainageTo

From GSLocation as gs
INNER JOIN MultiAttributes as ma on ma.MultiAttributeId = gs.MultiAttributeId
WHERE ma.Direction = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You should be able to do:

```
update t
    set to = from,
        from = to
    where direction = 2;
```

Of course `to` and `from` need to be escaped because they are SQL keywords.

Note that the SQL standard is defined so this will work (the right side of the assignment comes from the old values).  However, not all databases support the standard in this respect, which is why tagging questions with the appropriate database is important.

Comment: Hopefully this is not run on MySQL :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer my problem is direction is inner joined from another table

Answer (score -1):

```
update t
set to = from,
    from = to
where direction = 2;
```

To and from should be escaped cz they are SQL keywords

Comment: This is identical to the existing answer and doesn't add anything that one doesn't already cover. I'd recommend deleting this answer.

Comment: Again, hopefully this is not run on MySQL :-)